# Why am I getting very different measurement results on a breadboard?

Tags: current, current-measurement, multimeter, breadboard

I have an AC to DC multiple output adapter. It has the following output:

[image: Adapter output]

I set the voltage to 5V. When I measure the supplied current, I get 3.26A.

Then I connect an output to it:

[image: Output]

When I measure the supplied current now, I get 3.23A.

Then I try to measure the current on a breadboard:

[image: Breadboard measurement]

And I get 0.02A!

What is going on? Why is this happening?

More interestingly, I have discovered that the LED on my adapter gets dim proportional to the current it supplies. However, in all three measurements, although the results differ (especially the last result), the LED gets exactly the same amount dimmer. So this is a curious point as well.

Could you explain why the measurement on breadboard differs so much?

Comment: Stop "measuring current" without a load in between. You'll kill the power supply. And your meter when you try it with a more capable power supply.

Comment: It appears that you do not understand how the breadboard is internally connected, and how the measurement differs from the original method you did and the result given by the breadboard..

Comment: Please read answers to this question http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/34229/what-not-to-do-with-a-multimeter before you do the next unwise thing with your multimeter.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are short-circuiting the adapter, first with the ammeter, and then with the breadboard. Both are not good for the adapter.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUZLbu.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

The dashed boxes represent the equivalent circuit of your supply and your ammeter; numbers are very approximate.

On the right hand side you see the ammeter shorting out your supply and causing it to overheat and probably fail in short order. On the left hand side you see the same thing happening except most of the current is flowing through the solderless breadboard and only a small amount (the voltage drop in the conductors) is getting to the ammeter. If the conductors were perfect the meter would read zero since you've shorted the meter (as well as the adapter).

This is bad practice and you will eventually damage something.. putting an ammeter across a voltage source can cause serious injury or death if the source is capable of a lot of current, and certainly can damage the meter or the electronics. Don't ever do it.

Comment: Thanks. But how should I measure the supply voltage of my adapter? That is: How should I measure the max current my adapter can supply at a fixed voltage output?

Comment: Look up the datasheet. Right now you are just relying on the short-circuit or overheating protection of your adapter.

Comment: Do some ammeters not have current protection? Every meter I've used (up to 10A) has a fuse to protect it from overcurrent. And I've managed to blow a few fuses when accidentally leaving the meter on a current measuring setting when I wanted to measure voltage. It's certainly not a good idea to do it purposely, but do some meters fail catastrophically if you overload its current capacity?

Comment: @Johnny Yes, not all have fuses in the high current range (sometimes the leads just go directly to the shunt), and of those which have fuses, many are woefully inadequate to safely interrupt large fault currents. People have died when industrial mains is involved. See [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaIszMlrQNE) for an extreme example. Also [this.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HaIszMlrQNE) Modern Fluke multimeters are properly fused (big cartridge fuses inside) for such situations (see 'CAT III-600V' etc.).

Comment: @SpehroPefhany you linked the same video twice.

Comment: @DanNeely et al Correct 2nd link is [here](http://ecmweb.com/arc-flash/case-deadly-arc-flash).

Answer (score 6):

[image]

The 3.2A is now flowing through the short you have on your breadboard.

Try putting black wires on the blue line of breadboard pins.

Another bit of advice. Unless your power supply is current limited you might do it damage shorting it out like this.

Answer (score 5):

In your breadboard setup you have put the ammeter/DMM in parallel with the source, which is shorted through the breadboard. In your first setup the ammeter was in series with the source, that's why it correctly measured its short-circuit current.

In general, 3A through a breadboard is not a good idea. And neither is shorting a supply that's not designed for it.

Answer (score 5):

What you are measuring is the short circuit current of the power supply.  This is rarely a useful figure.

Normally, you would just trust the maker's specifications to give the maximum useful current that the supply can deliver.

If you don't trust the specs, you can (maybe) determine the maximum current by measuring the supply's output voltage while drawing increasing current from the supply - when the voltage drops too much, you've exceeded the maximum permissible current.  This method may work OK with a regulated power supply, but with a cheap unregulated supply it may be difficult to determine how much voltage drop is too much.

If you have an oscilliscope, you can watch for ripple on the output voltage - when the ripple voltage is "too high", you are drawing too much current.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have the + and - shorted out in the same track on the breadboard.  The breadboard track will probably be getting hot.  It is not a good idea to put an ammeter directly across the power supply like you have done in any of your examples anyway.

Comment: Yes but why does the result come up different?

Comment: Move the black wires to the track above and you should get the same results that you did in your previous tests.  The way you have it wired at the moment, most of the current will be flowing through your short circuit and bypassing the ammeter.

Comment: It comes out at basically zero at the breadboard because you have all the four wires plugged in there shorted together along one of the breadboard power rails.

Answer (score 4):

[image]

You have created a massive short circuit.